# Важна ли видеокарта для сервера?

Tags: windows, сервер, rdp, gpu

Есть обычный компьютер (года 2008 выпуска) в качестве сервера на базе Windows 7 x64. Воткнут в розетку и с интернетом. Все подключения к нему осуществляются через RDP если необходимо что-то запустить/настроить. В остальное время молотит без участия пользователя. Хочется максимально снизить шум и тепловыделение. Встроенного видео нет. Другие матери, из имеющихся, оборудованы меньшим количеством разъёмов под оперативку.

Отсюда встал вопрос:

> Какие минимальные требования к видеокарте для RDP подключений
>   (максимум 2 подключения)?

Что имею:

> PCI-E GeForce 7600GT (стоит в данный момент и шумит), какая-то PCI
>   плата с 1-2МБ памяти из конца 90-х (используется для восстановления BIOS
>   видеокарт). Что-то типа такого [S3 Trio](https://1.allegroimg.com/s1440/01c08a/49b01c104e9cb86b48236cf02931).

Comment: Пожалуй присоединюсь к вопросу в части запуска компа вообще без видеокарты. Как раз сегодня притащили похожее счастье, хочу его в skeenless варианте забросить на полку на даче, и пусть торренты по ночам на безлимите тянет. Но в ту полку куда хочу забросить с видюхой не влазит. Иксы там вааще не планируются ибо нафиг не нужны.

Comment: без "видеокарты" не запустите. Однако запустите если процессор умеет. Если быть точнее, то  уже несколько лет все материнки выпускаются с разъемом под монитор, вам лишь остается быть уверенным что процессор умеет  в видео.

Comment: "без "видеокарты" не запустите. Однако запустите если процессор умеет" :D

Comment: Ребят, могу сказать в.карат не умеет значение вообще - как вам написал  @zalex. При RDP подключение используются ресурсы локальной машины а не сервера к которому идет подлючение. У нас в офисе 10 удаленных машин в разных странах, все работают на 1-2u лезвиях только со встроенным видео необходимое для локального доступа к   BIOS. О том запустится ли машина без видео, сказать ничего не могу - зависит от матери и встроенной поддержке в процессоре. В supermicro есть IPMI что позволяет настраивать машину вообще без видео железки, хотя еще не встречал плат без встроенных VGA.

Comment: Меня больше интересовал вопрос " буду ли я иметь проблемы с RDP на видяхе PCI c 1-2МБ на борту? Т.е. будет ли поддерживаться разрешение клиента, а не максимально доступное для видео адаптера?

Comment: @Rootware Проверил - подключаюсь по RDP к своему ноуту Thinkpad 420 Win10 - максимальное разрешение - 1366x768 с моего рабочего компа на  GNU/Linux-Fedora через  Remmina, где есть в настройках опции: использовать разрешение клиента или собственное выбрал 1400х1050 и подключился без проблем.

Comment: @Hellseher Спасибо за информацию. Осталось карту с работы принести мне. :)

Comment: Как обходной вариант - аппаратные заглушки рублей за 200, можно у майнеров спросить. Как радикальный - linux + SSH =)

Comment: А какие задачи там будут крутиться?

Comment: @donRumata консольные приложения и БД. Основная нагрузка на память, проц и HDD.

Comment: А зачем тогда винда?

Comment: @donRumata консольные приложения разные бывают, равно как и базы данных.

Comment: Да, я слышал про это.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RDP не использует ресурсы видео карты, подключается через собственный виртуальный драйвер. Но для запуска самого сервера видео карта нужна. (При определенных условиях компьютер/сервер можно запустить и без видео-карты).

> ... На сервере RDP использует собственный видеодрайвер для визуализации вывода, создавая информацию рендеринга в сетевых пакетах с использованием протокола RDP и отправки их по сети клиенту. На клиенте RDP получает данные рендеринга и интерпретирует пакеты в соответствии с вызовами API интерфейса графического устройства Microsoft Windows (GDI). Для входного пути события клиентской мыши и клавиатуры перенаправляются от клиента к серверу. На сервере RDP использует свой собственный драйвер клавиатуры и мыши для приема этих событий клавиатуры и мыши. ...

[о протоколе RDP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/remote-desktop-protocol)

Comment: «Но для запуска самого сервера видео карта нужна.» — я немного не понял, откуда такой вывод

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь шум на 4-5 дБ станет меньше. Есть смысл воткнуть раритетную карту "чтобы комп запустился".

Comment: @andreymal в комментариях к вопросу это упомянули. Да, возможно без видео (при определенных условиях), но зачем? Поставили простую карту, запустили, при необходимости подключились. Встроенные видеокарты сейчас отлично справляются с подобной задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно понимать что RDP - это протокол. Ваш сервер в общем случае может быть вообще без видеокарты, но тогда не запуститься ваша операционная система. 
Чтобы быть точнее - когда вы подключаетесь по RDP, то отрисовка происходит у вас на компьютере, но не на сервере.
 Сервер вам передает лишь данные. Так что требований к видеокарте на сервере нет вообще ни каких.